# IntelliJ IDEA 15 - How to migrate task history between projects?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-15

I have been using IntelliJ IDEA 15 for close to a year now, and using the same project this whole time, where I have created Tasks to basically act as workspaces for various work assignments so I can group files I've touched based on the assignment title. I've recently had an issue in my project workspace where I am basically being forced to create a new workspace, and thus a new project in IntelliJ. The problem is that this new project has none of my Task history in it.

Does anyone know if it's possible, and if so, how, to migrate this Task history from one project to another?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Tasks are saved in YOUR_PROJECT/.idea/workspace.xml so you can backup this file and if needed you can just copy and paste these lines defining tasks to the other workspace.xml file. This is the example of one:

```
<configuration default="false" name="my-debug-task" type="JavascriptDebugType" factoryName="JavaScript Debug" uri="http://localhost:4200">
      <mapping url="webpack:////home/marcin/Sprawozdania/Inzynierka/sqap/sqap-ui/src" local-file="$PROJECT_DIR$/sqap-ui/src" />
      <mapping url="webpack:////home/marcin/Sprawozdania/Inzynierka/sqap/sqap-ui" local-file="$PROJECT_DIR$/sqap-ui" />
      <method />
    </configuration>
```

Addittionaly In workspace.xml you need to add reference of copied task to:

```
 <project> 
     <component>
         <list>
```

like here :

```
<list size="3">
      <item index="0" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JavaScript Debug.my-debug-task" />
      <item index="1" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="JavaScript Debug.Unnamed" />
      <item index="2" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="Maven.config start -devs" />
</list>
```